# Should I use AWS Glue or Spark on EMR for processing binary data to parquet format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, binary, aws-glue, amazon-emr

I have a work requirement of reading binary data from sensors and produce parquet output results for Analytics.

- For storage I have chosen s3 and Dynamodb.
- For processing engine I’m confused on how to choose between AWS EMR or AWS Glue.
- Data processing code base will be maintained in python coupled with Spark.

Please post your suggestion on choosing between AWS EMR or AWS Glue.

Answer (score 1):

It's an opinion based question and now you have AWS EMR Serverless.

**AWS Glue** is 1) more managed and thus with restrictions, and 2) imho issues with crawling for schema changes to consider, 3) own interpretation of dataframes 4) and less run-time configuration and 5) less options for serverless scalability. There seems to a few bugs etc. that keep on popping up.

**AWS EMR** is 1) an AWS platform easy enough to configure, 2) with the AWS flavour of what they think the best way of running Spark is, 3) some limitations in terms of subsequently scaling down resources when using dynamic scaling out, 4) a platform that uses Spark so there will be a bigger pool of persons to hire, 5) allowing bootstrapping of software not standardly supplied, and selection of standard software, such as, say, HBase.

So, comparable to an extent. And divergent in other ways; AWS Glue is ETL/ELT, AWS EMR is that with more capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Using Glue / EMR depends on your use-case.

EMR is a managed cluster of servers and costs less than Glue, but it also requires more maintenance and set-up overhead. You can not only run Spark but also other frameworks on EMR like Flink.

Glue is serverless Spark / Python and really easy to use. It does not run on the latest Spark version and abstracts a lot of Spark away, in a good but also in a bad sense, that you can not set specific configurations very easily.

Comment: I just had a doubt since mostly glue job runs on data formats like csv,json & parquet.since my data is somewhat like semi structured I’m not able to take up with glue as a option .if there are any ways to tweak and read binary data please let me know or can I proceed with a EMR as a option directly

Comment: There is no difference, you can just call spark.read.format("binaryFile").load("s3path") in your Glue Job (Glue 3.0).